# Differentiation Under the Integral Sign w Variable Substitution

Tags: real-analysis, integration, analysis, derivatives, bounds-of-integration

Let $f\in C^1(B_\rho(\xi))$, $\xi\in\mathbb{R}^n$ and $\rho>0$. I wish to show

$$ \frac{d}{d\rho} \int_{B_\rho(\xi)} f(x)\ dx = \frac{1}{\rho} \int_{B_\rho(\xi)} nf(x) + x\cdot Df(x)\ dx $$

I'm using the following fact: let $f\in C^1(\mathbb{R}^n)$, $\psi\in C^1(\mathbb{R}^{n+1})$ where $\psi(y,\rho) = f(y\rho)$ for $y\in\mathbb{R}^n$ and $\rho>0$. Then

$$ \frac{\partial}{\partial\rho} \psi(y,\rho) = \frac{1}{\rho} \sum_{i=1}^n y_i \frac{\partial \psi(y,\rho)}{\partial y_i} $$

I've begun with the variable substitution $x=y\rho$ which implies $f(x) = f(y\rho) = \psi(y,\rho)$. Then

$$ \frac{\partial}{\partial\rho} f(x) = \frac{\partial}{\partial \rho} \psi(y,\rho) = \frac{1}{\rho} \sum_{i=1}^n y_i \frac{\partial \psi(y,\rho)}{\partial y_i} $$

Here's the part I'm stuck on. Is the following correct?

$$ \frac{1}{\rho} \sum_{i=1}^n y_i \frac{\partial \psi(y,\rho)}{\partial y_i} = \frac{1}{\rho} \bigg[x \cdot Df(x)\bigg] $$

I think I'm forgetting an important step with the $B_\rho(\xi)$ in the bounds of integration and/or the $dx$ with the variable substitution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

\begin{align}
\frac d{d\rho}\int_{B_\rho(\xi)}f(x) \ dx 
&\overset{1.}{=} \frac{d}{d\rho}\int_{B_1(0)} f(\xi + \rho y) \ \rho^{n}dy 
\\&\overset{2.}{=} \int_{B_1(0) }y\cdot \nabla f(\xi+\rho y)\rho^n + f(\xi+\rho y) \  n\rho^{n-1} \ dy 
\\&\overset{3.}{=} \frac{1}{\rho} \int_{B_\rho(\xi)} nf(x) + (x-\xi)\cdot Df(x)\ dx\end{align}
where:

1. Change of variables $x-\xi= \rho y $, means that $y$ is in $B_1(0)$, and $dx = \rho^n dy$.
2. Follows from product rule, $$ \frac d{d\rho}(fg) = (\frac d{d\rho} f )g + f \frac{d}{d\rho} g  $$and chain rule,
   $$ \frac d{d\rho} f(\vec X(\rho)) = (\nabla f)(\vec X(\rho)) \cdot\left(\frac d{d\rho} \vec X (\rho)\right).$$
3. Undoing the change of variables $x-\xi= \rho y$. Note $\rho^{n-1} dy = \frac1\rho dx$.

$Df = \nabla f$ is the gradient of $f$. Regularity is used in step 2 to allow differentiation under the integral sign.

There is an additional term which is a multiple of
$$ \int_{B_\rho (\xi)} \xi \cdot \nabla f = \int_{B_\rho(\xi)} \nabla_x \cdot (\xi f(x)) \ dx = \int_{\partial B_\rho (\xi)} f \xi\cdot n $$

Comment: Great answer. I will erase mine after. I'm curious about something : is it equal to $\int_{\partial B_\rho(\xi)}f(x)dx$ ? (see my answer)

Comment: @Surb it should be. I guess there's a clever way of using Gauss theorem to show this but I don't see it

Comment: @Surb, I have been careless and I don't think the answer before was right. Do you think the claimed formula is still correct, and if yes, how would you remove this extra term I found? I feel like this makes more sense, since $x-\xi$ is normal to $\partial B_r (\xi)$

Comment: I think the OP forgot $(x-\xi)$ (or maybe $\xi=0$). Otherwise I don't think that his formula would be correct.

Comment: @Surb thank you very much for for comments.